# How to let the view draw the empty part when the tab is hidden on React Native?

Tags: react-native, tabs, velo

I am using the wix's react-native-navigation. It is a sample project from their branch. But I find that if the tabbar is hidden, the view will have an empty space. How to resolve it? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it, but I assume setting a negative `marginBottom` when the bar is hidden would do the trick